# Caught on a persistent issue with JS, nav bar active class not switching properly

Tags: javascript, class, nav

I've been using this [code snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dot-navigation-with-tooltips) to add in a vertical dot nav to a one page site, which smooth scrolls to a section when one of the links are clicked, and keeps a highlight on the active section. I did a lot of tweaking to the css to make it look how I wanted, and then replaced the sections.

So this is [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/tibevr/zma4t3pz/2/) in a jsfiddle, and the main issue I am having is the active class not changing properly, and making the side nav bar mess up. I've posted the JS below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.awesome-tooltip').tooltip({
    placement: 'left'
});   

$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
  dotnavigation();
});

function dotnavigation(){

    var numSections = $('section').length;

    $('#side-nav li a').removeClass('active').parent('li').removeClass('active');     
    $('section').each(function(i,item){
      var ele = $(item), nextTop;

      console.log(ele.next().html());

      if (typeof ele.next().offset() != "undefined") {
        nextTop = ele.next().offset().top;
      }
      else {
        nextTop = $(document).height();
      }

      if (ele.offset() !== null) {
        thisTop = ele.offset().top - ((nextTop - ele.offset().top) / numSections);
      }
      else {
        thisTop = 0;
      }

      var docTop = $(document).scrollTop();

      if(docTop >= thisTop && (docTop < nextTop)){
        $('#side-nav li').eq(i).addClass('active');
      }
    });   
}

/* get clicks working */
$('#side-nav li').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
      posi,
      ele,
      padding = 0;

    ele = $(id);
    posi = ($(ele).offset()||0).top - padding;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:posi}, 'slow');

    return false;
});
```

It works fairly well on the jsfiddle, but I am putting this code into squarespace, and on there it ends up like [this](https://gyazo.com/fa3912b1742f076391652967529402ea) where all of the buttons highlight when you try to change active classes.

I have tried to isolate the bug by going through the html, css, and the js, but I don't have enough knowledge of JS to be able to edit the script to fix it.
I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Link to [broken squarespace](https://sophie-arnold-gyz4.squarespace.com/oodkasokdoakas-1/)

Comment: Might be hard to diagnose without a link to it broken in squarespace. Unless someone has run into the same problem in the past.

Comment: @stwilz edited the link in, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet, the sample page is designed with continuous sections, so the method *ele.next()* will return next sections. In your squarespace page, the sections is not continuous, so method *ele.next()* will return empty and the code is not working.

Your could try to modify function *dotnavigation* like this

```
function dotnavigation(){

    var numSections = $('section').length;

    $('#side-nav li a').removeClass('active').parent('li').removeClass('active');     
    var sections = $('section');
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++)  {

      var ele = $(sections[i]), nextTop;

      //console.log(ele.next().html());

      if (i < sections.length - 1) {
        nextTop = $(sections[i + 1]).offset().top;
      }
      else {
        nextTop = $(document).height();
      }

      if (ele.offset() !== null) {
        thisTop = ele.offset().top - ((nextTop - ele.offset().top) / numSections);
      }
      else {
        thisTop = 0;
      }

      var docTop = $(document).scrollTop();
      console.log(thisTop);

      if(docTop >= thisTop && (docTop < nextTop)){
        $('#side-nav li').eq(i).addClass('active');
      }
    }
}
```

I've updated your code sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zma4t3pz/33/).

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! That modified code works a lot better, but I notice the class changing is still a bit weird, gif here: https://i.gyazo.com/d59aba6427a78af90fd9b2189ea2194f.gif, two are highlighted at each time. Was wondering if you knew what might be making that hang up?

Comment: This is problem when scrolling to the edge between sections. I have updated the demo here https://jsfiddle.net/zma4t3pz/33/

Comment: That works great thanks! I notice that when adding more than 4 (trying with 5) navigation links, the fifth one highlights when you on the fourth. Apart from that it works great. :)

Comment: Strangely, the code works on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tibevr/zma4t3pz/46/), but not on squarespace (gif link: https://i.gyazo.com/1f2a2d97d52d7fb109006faca7ed8433.gif)

Comment: hey @trungduong I got it working by just using 4 nav links, to avoid using the 5th, but attempted to add new sections and link to those instead of the ones i had when you helped, now am having an issue where the active class of dot 4 turns on at a random point on the page above the section its linked it. Was hoping you might be able to help me/have an idea of whats going on?

[page link](https://sophie-arnold-gyz4.squarespace.com/oodkasokdoakas-1)

Comment: @tibevr Sorry, I've checked your link. But when I click on 4th dot, it's navigated to Design Process page - https://ibb.co/eki1Hc. Is it not expected behavior?

Comment: That is expected behaviour, but do you notice how the fourth dot highlights when the third dot is selected and navigated to? Thats my issue